# I have sent SYN tokens and are stuck in my ETH wallet. What can I do?

Tags: erc-20, tokens, cpp-ethereum

I have my SYN tokens stuck in my ETH wallet and can see them in etherscan. Anyway to send them out back to the original address the tokens weren't sent from?

0xF66Bd3fa316aBD9c44492bc92AefC90652AE9311
That ETH wallet (from coinbase.com) holds the tokens

They were sent from: (0xe29f430e83c83e01e60ee12aa8815c013775ae5d) my coinbase wallet.

The tokens should have been sent to this SYN wallet(from coinbase.com): 0xa502Bf2070e9c5AddbDcFB48ff605CE069559DFE

Here is the transaction hash: 0x5cb9a2114ccbbb9b51e3b750791a14f2c0536de4e37ec1d245283f49605d7630

Any way to undo the contract or something to return the tokens? Or are they lost forever? Anyone know what I can do?

https://etherscan.io/tokenholdings?a=0xf66bd3fa316abd9c44492bc92aefc90652ae9311

Comment: Anyway to use an exchange to relocate the tokens out of the ETH wallet and pay the ETH transaction fee?